# Unable to install Openstack with Devstack on Ubuntu 20

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, ubuntu-20.04, devstack, openstack-glance

I have been trying to install Openstack on Ubuntu 20 O.S VM in Virtualbox and getting the following error.

```
[Call Trace]
./stack.sh:1311:start_glance
/opt/stack/devstack/lib/glance:480:die
[ERROR] /opt/stack/devstack/lib/glance:480 g-api did not start
Error on exit
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2021-02-08-170119.txt for details
```

I have searched with the error but none of that works. The local.conf file content is as follows.

```
~/devstack$ cat local.conf
[[local|localrc]]

# Password for KeyStone, Database, RabbitMQ and Service
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD

# Host IP - get your Server/VM IP address from ip addr command
HOST_IP=192.168.122.1
disable_service etcd3
```

I have tried ./unstack and ./clean several times. If anyone has encountered the error and found a fix or knows the workaround, please help me. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can anyone please help...

Answer (score 1):

As stated on Devstack page, Devstack best tested on Ubuntu 18.04. Thats why, it may have problems on Ubuntu 20.04. I suggest that you use Ubuntu 18.04 instead. I had tested it on Ubuntu 18.04 and it basicly works.
Another question; why do you disable etcd3 ? what is purpose?

Answer (score 0):

As of [September 2021](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/index.html):

> DevStack attempts to support the two latest LTS releases of Ubuntu, the latest/current Fedora version, CentOS/RHEL 8 and OpenSUSE.
>
> If you do not have a preference, Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) is the most tested, and will probably go the smoothest.

I've installed it using Ubuntu Server 20.04.3. I found that I needed to remove a couple of packages first. The installer can be a bit sensitive to existing files:

> ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'simplejson'. It is a distutils installed project

```
apt remove -y python3-simplejson
```

> ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'pyasn1-modules'. It is a distutils installed project

```
apt remove -y python3-pyasn1-modules
```

I note that I attempted the install on 2 machines. One is a laptop, the other a Xeon powered micro server. The install is fine on the more powerful machine but on the laptop I've had a lot more problems, because of timeouts. So the "g-api did not start" might relate to this.

One option which isn't good is to manually edit the systemd service file and add a large TimeoutSec value to the Service section. It would be better to set a larger global systemd default.